# Consuming REST web service like SOAP

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap, jaxb

I have an application which simply works as a translator between two web service.
Hence, main goal/operation in my application is transformation from consumer XML to Gate Way XML.

So far we have integrated two SOAP web services by creating Proxy.

**Now, the challenge is** we require to integrate a REST web service and we can't create Proxy of it. However, request and response are in XML format.

To consume this service (REST) we have thought about following approach:

1. Create JAXB classes by createing shcema using sample XMLs of service

Can you please suggest us any better approach?
Is it possible to create Object/Class from XML at run-time? (UnMarshalling run-time)

Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, i believe, that's what JAXB is meant for. You can also look at XStream if you want an alterantive.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Here i am looking for different approach to consume the REST web service like SOAP.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'like SOAP'.

Comment: 'like SOAP' means creating proxy.

Comment: well, two technologies come to mind. using JAX-RS implementations like Jersey, Restlet or RESTeasy. they all provide some sort of integration with JAXB. The other option which is not so easy would be to use XSLT.

Comment: Thanks. XSLT i knew that :) and it's best approch also. However, there is learning curve so planning to avoid it. The other options sounds good to me, have to look into this. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try the REST Framework Jersey which contains the Jackson/JAX-RS Framework.
The JAX-RS Framework can you use to marshall or unmarshalling objects.

Follow these tutorial for example:

> http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

Jersey Framework:

> jersey.java.net/